# Stormcrawler: Storing Outlinks of crawled Pages in Elasticsearch

Tags: stormcrawler

I would like to store the outlink Array (URLs, Anchors) in the content Index of ElasticSearch. Can i just add a new line to indexer.md.mapping for this or is it necessary to create a new parsefilter to store Outlinks of crawled Pages?

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question thanks!

The indexer generates the fields for ES from the metadata. To store the outlinks in the *content* index, you'll need to create a custom ParseFilter and turn the outlinks from [ParseResult](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/ParseFilter.java#L45) to key/values in the metadata, then configure  *indexer.md.mapping* accordingly.